Oracle SQL - How to cross-reference two columns from a table to the same column from another table
I have two tables:
Table 1 (Trip): trip_ID, mileage, budget, origin, destination
Table 2 (Location): location_ID, location_name
trip.origin = location.location_ID AND trip.destination = location.location_ID
What query do I need to write to return the location name (instead of location_ID) along the rest of information from table 1?
Trip_ID, Mileage, Budget, Origin (location_name), Destination (location_name)
Thank you!

Didn't test it but something like this should work:
select 
coalesce(l.location_name, 'Unknown') as location_name,
t.*
from
trip t left outer join location l on l.location_id = t.origin


JOIN to the location table twice:
SELECT trip_id,
       mileage,
       budget,
       lo.location_name AS origin,
       ld.location_name AS destination
FROM   trip t
       INNER JOIN location ld
       ON (t.destination = ld.location_id)
       INNER JOIN location lo
       ON (t.origin = lo.location_id)

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE Trip (trip_ID, mileage, budget, origin, destination) AS
  SELECT 1, 42, 2.15, 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 35, 3.14, 2, 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Location (location_ID, location_name) AS
  SELECT 1, 'Here' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'There' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Somewhere' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



TRIP_ID
MILEAGE
BUDGET
ORIGIN
DESTINATION




1
42
2.15
Here
There


2
35
3.14
There
Somewhere



fiddle
